# Google keeps changing my font to Helvetica what do i need to do?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I wanted to use the font 'Lato' so I added the google fonts link to my html and css but when I open my website it is in Helvetica. I can't fix the problem.

```
html,
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I believe that you sould provide a working example. We don't know how your html continues.

Comment: Is that the actual position of your css in the html? If that is the case, your css should be inside a ```<style>``` tag inside the ```<head>```

Comment: One problem I see in @MSclavi's snippet is that the font weight is reset to 400, because apparently Lato isn't available in 300. So I'm thinking, could there be circumstances where the inability to use Lato 300 could result in another font being displayed?

Comment: In the snippet what type of font are you seeing?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is an issue with your tags on the html file, but here you have a snippet of your code working.

```css
html,
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  <span>Hello</span>
</body>
</html>
```